# Network Bridge shows Unidentified network on second PC

Tags: networking, bridge

I have a Laptop and a desktop PC. Laptop has a WIFI connection , I want to connect Laptop to Desktop for internet connection as dekstop doesnt have WiFi card.
On my laptop I have Windows 8.1 and on PC windows10

So I tried to bridge connection, steps are :
1.Plugged Ethernet cable one end to laptop other to PC
2.got ip info by typing ipconfig/all
3.Selected Ethernet and Wifi connection and selected Bridge Connection.
4.Network Bridge has my Wifi Name on it.
5.On bridge connection, under properties selected IPV4 then its properties and set static IP, default gateway and DNS to what my Wifi info was.
6.On my PC disabled and enabled the connection and it shows Unidentified Network

Comment: Step 2 and step 5 are not needed. Please undo any changes you made on step 5. Additionally report back with the ipconfig /all info from th desktop. Make sure your WiFi is connected and does your laptop have internet?